# does Clojure on Hotspot require any non-FOSS components

Tags: java, clojure, open-source, jvm-hotspot

When I use Clojure with the (Sun/Oracle) Hotspot VM, what other software components are required, at a minimum, by Clojure? Are all those (minimal) components Open Source?

I see that the [Hotspot VM is Open Source](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/) but I don't think any Java libraries are included in that component. I know Clojure needs Java strings and regular expressions for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's good news and bad news and good news.

- The Oracle distributions of Java includes the full Java SE libraries.  In fact, any Java distribution does.
- But ... the Oracle distributions is not totally open source.  Certainly, the source code bundle that is included in a Java 7 Hotspot JDK says this in the source code headers:

> Copyright (c) 1997, 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.

- But ... Oracle distributions are built from a source code base that is *derived* from OpenJDK, and OpenJDK is fully Open Source.

So if you want to see the Java SE source code, and the source code of the JVM, it is pretty much all in the OpenJDK repositories.  It is possible that there is a bit of "secret sauce/source" for Hotspot that is held back, but I'm not aware of any public details.

And if you want to be 100% kosher OSS, you have the option of using an OpenJDK-based distribution; e.g. as available for most recent Linux distros from their respective package installer repositories.  You could also download and build the source from the OpenJDK repositories.

---

> When I use Clojure with the (Sun/Oracle) Hotspot VM, what other software components are required, at a minimum, by Clojure?

The complete Java SE libraries.  I don't think you can subset the library because a Clojure program *could* use any of the standard Java classes.  (And if you did try to subset the Java standard libraries you'd have to analyse all of Clojure and its standard libraries to figure out what subset of Java is required.  And it would most likely be a moving target.)

> Are all those (minimal) components Open Source?

Strictly speaking, it depends on where you get them from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stepen. I think the first bullet gets it wrong. HotSpot does not refer to Oracle's distro of Java. I believe in practice Hotspot always refers to a particular VM e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html

So there is no such thing as a "HotSpot" JDK (mentioned in the second bullet). However, the wikipedia page for OpenJDK says that OpenJDK consists of three parts (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK): the HotSpot VM, the Java class libraries, and javac. So I think the answer to my question is: "yes" since the JCL are part of OpenJDK.

Comment: Updated answer to address your "Hotspot" nitpick.  BTW: from a copyright perspective it is not relevant what is "part of OpenJDK" according to Wikipedia.  What is relevant is what files are in the "package" that you copy, and what is covered by the corresponding license.  Wikipedia has no legal standing / authority / relevance whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Stephen. Remaining nit: second bullet still refers to the "Java 7 Hotspot JDK" which is not a thing. Your stance that all the Java SE libs (JCL) are required is reasonable nevertheless it would be interesting to know which subset of those are actually required to make all of Clojure work. Lastly the point of referencing wikipedia was merely to inform myself and others as to what comprised the OpenJDK (JVM(hotspot),JCL,javac).

Answer (score 0):

A build of OpenJDK - either prebuilt from a Linux distro, such as RedHat's IcedTea, or built by hand from source (which with the new build-infra build is trivial - see AdoptOpenJDK for details) is all that you need to run Clojure.

You should not attempt to subset the Java class libraries - this will cause you a great deal of pain later for essentially zero benefit.

Comment: Agreed. Knowing that the whole JCL is Open Source, there wouldn't be any reason to subset it. On the other hand, it would be interesting to know which Java classes are actually necessary. That might be an interesting subject for a different stackoverflow question :)

Comment: The problem is that any Clojure code you could load could start requiring Java core classes that aren't present in your subset, and so things start breaking. An interesting, related question (in the pure Java world) is "what is the 'transitive dependency closure' of java.lang.Object?" - this is a much more complex question than it first appears.